Typing is not smooth and it stucks on Ubuntu 24.04
When I type anywhere, typing experience is not smooth. It gets stuck for shorter periods. 3-10 characters are not written while it is stuck and then they all appear at once after it unfreezes. IT has made the typing experience so terrible. Keyboard works fine with other OS and computers. When it is stuck, no other key or shorctut works.
This is not an issue with on screen keyboard but external usb keyboard. It only happens on Anti Ghosting (Gaming) keyboard. Not on other keyboards.
